# How to get the value of an Autocad attribute with Rust?

Tags: rust, autocad

I've been using Rust for a while now and I still haven´t found anything similar to what I want to do. I wanted to iterate through the blocks in a drawing and find a specific block with specific attributes.
Here is the code:

```rust
#![allow(non_snake_case)]
#![allow(unused_imports)]
use dxf::entities::*;
use dxf::Drawing;
use std::any::{Any, TypeId};
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::fmt;

#[allow(dead_code)]
fn main() {
    let mut omap = HashMap::new();
    let mut count: u16 = 0;

    // abre o arquivo
    let desenho = Drawing::load_file("file .dxf").unwrap();
    // itera sobre as entidades do arquivo
    let mut aux: String = String::new();

    for block in desenho.blocks() {
        if block.name == String::from("FL01") {
            count += 1;
            for e in block.entities.iter() {
                match e.specific {
                    EntityType::AttributeDefinition(ref attribute) => {
                        if attribute.text_tag == String::from("TIPO") {
                            aux.push_str(&String::from("-"));
                            omap.insert(attribute.text_tag.to_string(), attribute.value.clone());
                            println!("{}", attribute.value.clone());
                        } else if attribute.text_tag == String::from("SEQ-1") {
                            aux.push_str(&attribute.prompt);
                            aux.push_str(&String::from("-"));
                            omap.insert(
                                attribute.text_tag.to_string(),
                                attribute.value.to_string(),
                            );
                        }
                    }
                    _ => (),
                };
            }
        }
    }
    println!("{:?}, Quantidade:{}", omap, count);
}
```

The `attribute.value` does not return anything and I know, for a fact, that this attribute does have a value.
So, if anyone knows what could be causing this, please let me know.

Comment: Can you provide a file that this should work with? Also, the `dxf` crate has some documentation on the formats but it might be relevant to know which version you're using.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't provide the file because it belongs to a company. But, I am using the 2010 .dxf version.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to your other recent question, your code is inspecting the attribute *definitions* found within the block *definition*, as opposed to the attribute *references* held by a block *reference*.

You need to iterate over the objects held within the layout block (and block definitions if nested block references are desired), and test for the existence of a block *reference* object (`AcDbBlockReference`), for which you can then invoke the `GetAttributes` method to obtain the set of attribute references held by the block.

Comment: Would you please show me a code snippet?